# Oracle 00306 error on calling procedure with parameter - array of numbers

Tags: ado.net, oracle11g

I have a type defined in Types like this "`create or replace type numbers_table is table of numbers`". I have a procedure that has a parameter of this type (`ids_list IN numbers_table`).

On calling the procedure with Oracle Client I keep receiving the "..Wrong number or types of arguments ..." error.

I am passing this parameter like this:

```
    OracleParameter param1 = new OracleParameter("ids_list", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParamDirection.Input);
param1.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
param1.ArrayBindSize = new int[collectioncount];
param1.ArrayBindStatus = new OracleParameterStatus[collectioncount];
param1.Size = collectioncount;

for(int i = 0; i < collectioncount; i++)
{
param1[i].ArrayBindSize = 8000;
param1[i].ArrayBindStatus = new OracleParameterStatus.Success;

}

param1.Value = collection;
```

Still no luck  ... I have tried to change OracleDbType.Decimal to Double, Long, Int64 etc but nothing works for me.

Comment: what's the name of the procedure?

Comment: I finally made a workaround like that: passed to the procedure a parameter of a type declared in the package specification (an array of integers), then inside the package I converted it to the type defined in Oracle Types, to be able to make selects from it without actually looping through it. As I have been advised, there is some mapping necessary in the code to be able to use a parameter of a type defined in Oracle Types.